# Cron Job with a Curl

Tags: curl, scripting, cron

I just got through the first hurdle in requesting my keys for a connection. There's other routes I can take to achieve this, however I noticed CRON jobs can do this as well.

I'm looking for guidance on building a script with about 1,000 rows that between each line waits for 400 seconds.

```
curl -x POST https://api.example.com/a/b/c/c.json?key=123 -d 'data=feed'
timeout 400
curl -x POST https://api.example.com/a/b/c/c.json?key=123 -d 'data=feed'
timeout 400
curl -x POST https://api.example.com/a/b/c/c.json?key=123 -d 'data=feed'
```

The cron job would be created with a path to the script.

Help is appreciated, It's 3 AM and I'm out of Rockstar recovery lemonade (favorite code juice).

Answer (score 1):

can you wait 420 seconds instead?

```
*/7 * * * * curl whatever
```

- albeit, if you truly need sub-minute precision, a daemon is probably a better choice.

(generated the command with https://crontab-generator.org )

Comment: Well, as far as scheduling the CRON task I'm good to go as once per day.
However the Script that I need executed "script.sh" is where I tumbled over.

The code snippet above is what's in my SH script, and my SH script would need to run once per day, however it processes iteratively and after each curl post TIMEOUT for X seconds

Comment: @RaudelSolis 1000 rows, 400 seconds sleep between each row.. you can't do that once per day, 400*1000 = 400,000 seconds, 400000/60/60/24 = 4.63 days, you can at most do this once per 4 and a half days, circa, if you need a 400 seconds delay between each execution.

Comment: It appears my file is found by cpanel however the script is broken.
I get the server confirmation emails.

My current solution is to use a shell script in windows that looks like: CURL POST.... TIMEOUT 400 CURL POST TIMEOUT 400... and so on

Answer (score 0):

https://git-scm.com/ this was magic for my curl task, I can set and forget a job on a toaster (spare computer.)